# Is there a better way than brute force to maintain hub state? (Smart Home Group API)

Tags: logitech

Is there a better way to maintain hub state sync than periodic random checks?  The physical remote gets a notification nearly instantaneously of a state change on the hub so I assume it's subscribed somehow to push-updates.  Is the best approach to just send a GET request for the hub state every 30 seconds to a minute while idle, and every 5-10 seconds after an activity change? I don't want to bombard the servers with lots of requests but I'm not sure how to know when to unlock the UI after a successful activity initiation.

Answer (score 1):

The current Smart Home Group API does not provide notifications of Activity or device state changes. This is something Logitech expects to implement later this calendar year.